# Delphi livebinding TClientDataSet TStringGrid runtime

Tags: delphi, runtime, tclientdataset, tstringlist, delphi-xe5

in Firemonkey (XE5) I created a Frame with a TStringGrid and want to add a 
"procedure ShowData( aClientSet:TClientSet);"
in that pprocedure the rows of the Clientset shall be shown readonly with LiveBindings (TBindSourceDB ?) without knowing anything else of the dataset and WITHOUT DESIGNER ?
Please, how can this be done in runtime ?
And how to control that the Grid be refilled, if the Dataset closed and reopened outside the Frame (where to fire TBindings.notify) ?
Thx.

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me:

1. Include Data.Bind.EngExt, Fmx.Bind.DBEngExt, Fmx.Bind.Grid,
   System.Bindings.Outputs, Fmx.Bind.Editors, Data.Bind.Components,
   Data.Bind.Grid and Data.Bind.DBScope in your uses clause.
2. Assuming your TStringGrid is named grid1 and your dataset is called qry1 :

   var
       bds: TBindSourceDB;
       bdl: TBindingsList;
       gtd: TLinkGridToDataSource;
   begin
       bds := TBindSourceDB.Create(Self);
       bdl := TBindingsList.Create(Self);
       gtd := TLinkGridToDataSource.Create(bdl);

   gtd.DataSource := bds;
       gtd.GridControl := Grid1;

   bds.DataSet := qry1;
   end;

Hope this helps!  (I used a TFDQuery as my dataset, but I'm sure any TDataset descendant should work fine.)